# Status Bar blinks when awake from background state

Tags: ios, statusbar

In some of app's view controllers status bar is hidden. But when user opens the app from a background, status bar becomes visible for a second, and then hides. 
I tried:

1. to put `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES]`
    into `applicationWillEnterForeground:` method. However, status bar becomes visible **before** this method is called.
2. check status bar's visibility when `applicationWillResignActive`: 
   `self.isStatusBarHidden = [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarHidden ? YES : NO;`, but it returns `<nil>`. (Then I wanted to hide status bar and show it when `applicationWillEnterForeground` - this leads to a completely opposite situation)

How to solve this problem?

P.S. `View controller-based status bar appearance` in my .plist file is equal to NO and `Status bar is initially hidden` is equal to NO too.

Comment: What you want to achieve exactly ?

Comment: I want to stop status bar blinking when app is entering a foreground

Comment: Do you want to totally hidden status bar for your appliaction ???

Answer (score 0):

Are you keeping your settings like this?[image]

You need to check status bar style *Hide during application launch*.

Comment: @CatherineL. : I have taken the screenshot from Xcode 8.2.1 . You can only see these options if you select **Targets**.

Comment: There are only 2 options: "Hide status bar" and "Requires full screen". The  "Hide status bar" option totally hides status bar from the app. That's not what I need.

Comment: @CatherineL. : The "Hide status bar" option only hides during launch. In case of viewcontroller you have to write this method `-(BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden
{
    return YES;
}`

Comment: `preferStatusBarHidden` method doesn't get called.

Comment: @CatherineL. : Where did you write it?

Comment: In viewController.